# Error after upgrading OpenSSL on CentOs 6.5

Tags: centos, openssl

When I tried to upgrade OpenSSL on our test server it seemed to have failed. After multiple restarts of apache and even a server reboot I was still stuck with 1.0.1.

However when I tried to throw some commands at it today to implement custom DHParams I recieved the following error:

```
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It now seems that the upgrade has worked but something else has failed. I can't use

```
openssl version
```

or whatever else you can think of that uses OpenSSL, it keeps throwing the error at me.

Normally I would find my way accross the web to an answer but this time I can't.

I have found an [askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) but it doesn't resolve my problem.

The server is running CentOs 6.5 and the upgrade was done by following [this](https://syslint.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7/) tutorial, newer version of CentOs but that shouldn't make a difference right?

Please, help...

EDIT 11/05/2017 13.15 (Amsterdam)

So I was able to fix it after all after a little bit more Googlin'

I found a [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) which helped me

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.0e
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Was just about what I needed after that openssl was problem free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix it after all after a little bit more Googlin'

I found a [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) which helped me

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.0e
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Was just about what I needed after that openssl was problem free